# Programmed segues will not work properly

Tags: ios

I am running a program in xCode 7 and I would like to perform a segue based on the value of a certain string. Here is my viewDidLoad() code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    initialGreeting()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateGreeting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    if(name == ""){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

What matters in the code:

```
if(name == ""){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
}
```

I know this code is running because I had previously inserted a print statement which worked. What I don't understand is why the self.performSegueWithIndentifier isn't working? Somebody please explain this problem.

Comment: Show details about your storyboard. Did you even named the segues with the desired values?

Comment: Yes. The identifier for the segue is "segue" on the storyboard.

Comment: Provide an image of your storyboard, so we can analyze better.